# Why are the phases of a distorted sine wave always these four values?

Tags: phase, distortion

In this image I show how I distorted a sine wave with three defects in the transfer function, similar to what you might see in a real transistor or tube circuit. I did the FFT on it and the extracted the phases (phase=(degrees(arctan(harmonic.im/harmonic.re))) of over 300 harmonics. Why is there never a 22.5 or 13.6 degree number? They all seem very consistently those same 4 numbers.
[image: 3 distortion phase display]

Comment: which same 4 numbers?

Comment: you say you "distorted a sine wave"; how? Show the actual mathematics involved.

Comment: 0, 90, 180, 270. Can you read my spreadsheet?

Comment: I distort the sine wave by using a VLOOKUP function in Excel to equate a perfect sine wave to a 10,001 point transfer function I created, which perfectly simulates what a REAL device does to an incoming wave. if the input wave is a 0, the lookup table might return a zero, if I don't fiddle with the values in the lookup table, but if I do, I'm simulating a distortion. Since the zero value is passed twice (every value is, except the 90 degree value and the 270 degree value) you  an fully expect symmetry when a sine wave is applied, which you see very clearly in my graphic.

Answer (score 2):

Your artifacts are highly symmetric along the time axis. Namely, every peak and every zero position of the fundamental show time reversal symmetry.

This leads to the conincidence, that all harmonics must have their time inversion symmetry points (peaks/zeros) aligned with those of the fundamental. So they must always have a phase that comes in multiples of 90°.

If you go the other way:

1. randomly calculate 300 amplitudes and phases
2. add up these 300 corresponding sine waves

you will obtain a waveform that looks much less symmetrical.

Comment: That's actually very astute. But why would I do things "randomly" when noise is random, distortion is not. Distortion and Noise are two different things, or maybe you have never heard of THD+N.

Comment: The random bit is just too illustrate that harmonic distortion is not necessarily always in phase or quadrature of the fundamental and that your example does not express generality @DanBullard

Comment: Nope, I totally disagree, the distortion occurs at a particular point in the transfer function, it could be anyplace, but say it's at 45 degrees, it will happen again at 45+90 = 135 degrees, absolutely. If it doesn't there then that's hysteresis and you can measure that by noting the delta between what the harmonic phase would have been and dividing by the frequency of the harmonic, the answer will be in seconds. If I get a nail in my tire, when will I hear the classic "tick, tick, tick?" Will it vary randomly as I drive? Nope, it will always be tied PRECISELY to the speed of the car.

Comment: @DanBullard that is only valid if you produce the THD using your time domain function. As soon as you pack any frequency dependent element (say some echo), it's not general. Anyway your question is "why are all the phases multiples of 90°", which is a nongeneral case and explained in the answer.

Comment: @DanBullard Your assumption is also only valid if the input is time inversion symmetric,  like a pure sine wave, or triangle. Anything skewed will generally not have this phase alignment